# bash - padding find results

Tags: bash, awk, find, padding

I'm running the following command to get a directory listing:

```
find ./../ \
  -type f -newer ./lastsearchstamp -path . -prune -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.log' \
  | awk -F/ '{print $NF "                          - " $FILENAME}'
```

Is there some way I can format the output in a 2 column left indented layout so that the output looks legible?

The command above always adds a constant spacing between the filename and the path.

Expected output:

```
abc.txt            /root/somefolder/someotherfolder/
helloworld.txt     /root/folder/someotherfolder/
a.sh               /root/folder/someotherfolder/scripts
```

Comment: Could you explain me what `$FILENAME` suppose to be?

Comment: `man find` and look at the `-printf` option, you probably don't need awk or any other tool for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nice tool for this kind of thing is `column -t`. You just add the command on to the end of  the pipeline:

```
find ... | awk -F/ '{print $NF " - " $FILENAME}' | column -t
```